# flutter: Error: The non-abstract class 'RenderParagraphX' is missing implementations for these members, caused by sliding_up_panel-1.0.2

Tags: flutter, release, incompatibility

Since I updated flutter, yesterday, I am receiving the following error message:

```dart
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           23,5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/assorted_layout_widgets-1.3.4/lib/src/text_one_line.dart:207:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'RenderParagraphX' is missing implementations for these members:
     - RenderParagraph.getFullHeightForCaret
    Try to either
     - provide an implementation,
     - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
     - mark the class as abstract, or
     - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

    class RenderParagraphX extends RenderBox
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Applications/flutter%20env/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart:750:11: Context: 'RenderParagraph.getFullHeightForCaret' is defined here.
      double? getFullHeightForCaret(TextPosition position) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sliding_up_panel-1.0.2/lib/src/panel.dart:218:44: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
      VelocityTracker _vt = new VelocityTracker();
                                               ^
    ../../Applications/flutter%20env/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/velocity_tracker.dart:152:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      VelocityTracker(this.kind);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

So I assume sliding_up_panel-1.0.2 has some issue with the newest release.

Unless I want to rely on a soon release of 1.0.3, I guess my only chance is to roll back to the previous flutter release, right (ok, I could also disable all related functionality)?

Is there a simpler approach than to uninstall and re-install the previous version via shell commands. Last time I had quite some difficulties with some configuration files. Currently I am enjoying the neat update feature of IntelliJ IDEA (besides, I am using a Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can build again :-D

this is what I have done, in case some else experiences this problem:

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter upgrade
3. flutter clean

PS: Before, I removed all traces of sliding_up_panel, but still got the build errors. Now everything works, including the sliding_up_panel

Comment: tried but not work :(